# SVG's in Chrome and Edge get wrong MIME type when the page is viewed offline

Tags: google-chrome, svg, microsoft-edge

EDIT: This appears to have been fixed in Chrome 98. SVG's are back to behaving normally!

Admittedly a limited use-case, but when viewed from a server, calls to SVG images, e.g,

```
<img src="mydog.svg" alt="">
```

... are served with a MIME type of `svg+xml`, and work just fine. But when viewed offline, directly from the hard drive, with a `file://` protocol, Chrome and Edge put a MIME type of `text/plain` on them, and they fail to display. Firefox has no problem.

Anyone know how to defeat this behavior?

FWIW, the SVG files themselves are dead simple, like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="32" height="32">
    <g stroke="#fffbfb" stroke-width="40" >
    <path d="M135 135, 865 865 M135 865, 865 135" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Edit: If someone wants to play with this, here's a very stripped-down example. Just a minimal HTML page, and a minimal SVG file. Unzip, then double-click index.html to open in your browser locally. Firefox in Win11 works, Chrome in Win11 doesn't.

(now-dead link removed - no longer needed)

Comment: I can't reproduce that in Chromium 97 for Linux. Does your OS know about the SVG mime type? Does it make a difference if you add the XML prolog `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` at the start of the file?

Comment: This is the Google Chrome browser, version 97, in Windows 11. Nothing odd going on.

The XML prolog makes no difference.

Comment: One interesting discovery, however. There is no problem in any browser - Chrome, Firefox, or Safari - under macOS 11.6.3. It's only Chrome and Edge under Win11 that exhibit the misbehavior.

Comment: Like @ccprog writes you should add a XML declaration as the first line (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` should be fine). And then the MIME type should be `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: I did that. It made no difference.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with Edge and Chrome on Win11. I test your sample and it works well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuTiB.png. Which version of Edge are you using? Have you opened F12 devtools to check if there's any error in console?

Comment: Very strange. My default is Firefox, so Edge and Chrome are pretty much "right out of the box" - I haven't modified them at all. In Edge, I don't even have any extensions, no bookmarks, nothing. Both browsers are the latest released versions. No console errors. The file length is correct. The only obvious problem is what I posted originally - the file is being delivered with a MIME type of `text/plain`, which is what prevents the SVG from rendering. https://misterneutron.com/svgdemo/console.png

Comment: BTW, it doesn't even need a web page to display the problem. It fails if I simply right-click the SVG and tell Windows to "Open with... Google Chrome." Both Chrome and Edge download the file, rather than displaying it. No problem in Firefox.

Comment: It's so strange if we're using the exactly the same svg file to test. The svg file shows type as `svg+xml` in my Edge and Chrome. Is it helpful if you clear browser data and cache in Edge and Chrome and test again? Do you install any svg viewer on the computer and make it as the default app for svg file?

Comment: Cache-clearing didn't help. Firefox was set as the default for opening SVG's. I tried changing it to Chrome. No change.

Comment: Whatever the cause is, it's been around for a long time! Same issue, no solution posted: https://superuser.com/questions/1253395/how-do-i-get-chrome-to-open-local-svg-files-instead-of-downloading

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue but it looks like a chromium issue, I suggest that you can report an issue on [this site](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) to see if there's any feedback.

Comment: Done. We'll see what, if anything, they come back with! https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1294865

Comment: The browser gods must have heard me. This appears to have been fixed in Chrome 98!